# Minimising distance: distance formula

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I am writing a program in C. I want to find a solution by minimizing expression

```
D1+D2+......+Dn
```

where Di's are distances calculated by distance formula between 2 points. The above expression is in x & y variables

Now I will differentiate this expression and find the solution. My doubt is:

since in the above expression, all Di's will occur as square roots which will be difficult to solve. So instead we can solve for this expression:

```
D1^2 + D2^2 + ......+ Dn^2
```

Will the answer produced by the above expression will be same as that would have been produced by solving the original one?

I have checked for simple test cases such as n=2. It produces the correct answer. Is it true in general?

**If not, how this problem can be solved?**

Comment: For n=2, the sum of squares of distances is minimised at the point halfway between them, and the sum of distances is minimised anywhere along the line segment connecting them. I think you need to test n=3.

Comment: Ya. Now I am understanding the problem. But what is the correct way?

Comment: how about using other metric (instead of Euclidean)?

Comment: CAn u suggest me some links to look up that? I have absolutely no idea about any other metric.

Comment: Why do you need to find this centroid - are you sure you actually need to find *this* exact centroid?  I mean, just using the mean point (projected on the line) may be a reasonable approximation for many purposes, right?

Comment: For n=3, I think you can take any point inside of the triangle with corners at the points.

Comment: I have withdrawn my "yes" answer. It was wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even for 2d distances, it is not in general true that the minimum of `a^2 + b^2` is at the same location as the minimum of `a + b`.  It may be true for some very specific limited set of problems, of course.  If you're trying to find a counterexample, note that the squares overpenalize long distances; if you construct an example with a minimum containing at least one long distance, you've a good chance that the sum of squares has a different minimum.

What is the problem you are trying to solve?  It's quite possible that for your problem the distinction doesn't matter, of course; or that the minimum of the sum of squares is a cheaper problem and an easier first approximation to a final solution.

It may be obvious, but if the various distances are *unrelated*, then for each individual distance the square is minimal when the distance is and thus the sum of unrelated distances is minimal where the sum of the squares is.

**Edit Post update:** You're trying to find a centroid with the limitation that it lies on a particular line.  In general outlines then: you've only one degree of freedom, and you can do plain differentiation.  However, the result will have a sum of fractions with sqrt in the denominator; solving that algebraically in the general case isn't possible (AFAIK).  I'm not 100% positive, but I think you're in luck in that your distance-sum has no local minimum except the global one; in that case newton's method will converge reliably and fast.

So, if you can verify the assumption that there is only one local minimum, you're home free, and even if you can, you can achieve a pretty good result fairly reliably and detect *when* it goes wrong simply by comparing your newton-method computed minimum with a few reality check points (say, the orthogonal projection of each point onto the line).

Comment: I did not understand "overpenalize" thing. Please elaborate.

My problem is: I am given set of points on a plane. And I am given a equation of a line (2-D plane). Now I have to find a point on line such that sum of the distances from all the given points is minimized.

Comment: intuitively squares "increase" large numbers more than small numbers.  So a problem where the minimum involves a large distance and several small distances is likely to expose a different minimum for the squares case, since that one large distance will dramatically impact the overal sum.

Comment: So what is the correct way to solve this problem?please Give some idea.

Comment: In you specific example, imagine three points directly on the line.  If two points are on 0, and one point is at 10 (as measured along the line), then the minimum of the sum of distances from the centroid is at 0 (being 10 - you're 10 away from the one point at 10), but the minimum for the sum of squares will be at 10/3 (try it).

Comment: Means I should try solving the original equation by newton's method?

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I did not know that newtons method is so useful. I just negelected that in my "numerical analysis" course last semester. I should have done that course properly.

Comment: AFAIK: as far as I know.  Which in this case means I'm not sure ;-).  Newton's method is conceptually pretty easy; wikipedia (as so often) has a fair explanation.  The formula, in any case, is trivial.  (Note that newton's method find's zero crossings, so you need to apply it to the differential, not the original distance-sum!).  If newton's method diverges (which I'm almost positive it won't for your problem setting), (stochastic) gradient descent is even easier and more reliable, but also slower.

Comment: Ya at wikipedia entry,its written that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Practical_considerations , if for functions,taking out derivative is not easy, then we can use secant method. Can I use it?

Comment: well, the derivative shouldn't be that bad - give it a shot it'll end up looking like a sum of terms ala `(x-x0)/sqrt((x-x0)^2 + y0^2)` when the line is x-axis (which a transformation can ensure), or only slightly more complex if `y = mx + c` i.e. is a linear function of x rather than just 0 (and no transformation needed).  I'm sure the secant method will work too, however - but realize that you need the zero crossing *of the derivative* so even for the secant-method, you won't escape taking at least *one* derivative.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your effort.

Answer (score 2):

You have not tested enough. Minimizing `D1 + D2` is not the same as minimizing `D1^2 + D2^2` in general, although it may be for some particular `D1` and `D2`.

EDIT after you reminded me that you are only interested in distances in the plane:

In the case where `D1` and `D2` are distances in the geometric plane, the point in the plane that minimizes `D1^2 + D2^2` also minimizes `D1 + D2`, but
it breaks down with three points.

Try it with the three points (0,0), (1,0) and (10, 0):
Minimizing `|x|+|x-1|+|x-10|` is not the same as minimizing `x^2+(x-1)^2+(x-10)^2`

Comment: Ya I understand that. But since these are distances (all are positive) so I thought it may be the case. But for n=2, I have tested 15-20 cases. It gives the correct result. What is the correct way to solve the above problem.

Comment: but ~Ewan in his answer is saying that it is correct. Please clarify.

Comment: I think that Ewan did not understand that D1, ... Dn did not vary independently but as functions of the same x and y in his answer.

Comment: How minimizing D1+D2 is a line?

Comment: @nwonder Sorry, I was thinking of something else for a minute. Please forget that part of my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You are a bit unclear about the origin of your D1, D2, .. Dn but I assume you have a set of points P1, P2, ..., Pn in the x-y plane, and you want to find the point p0=(x0,y0) that minimises the sum of the distances between each point P1.. Pn and p0.

So your D1.. Dn are actually:

```
D1 = sqrt((x0-x1)^2 + (y0-y1)^2)
D2 = sqrt((x0-x2)^2 + (y0-y2)^2)
..
Dn = sqrt((x0-xn)^2 + (y0-yn)^2)
```

where `x1 .. xn` and `y1 ... yn` are known and `x0, y0` are unknown. And you want to minimise `D0`:

```
D0 = D1+D2+......+Dn
```

If this is correct then you want to find the [Geometric median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median). The wikipedia article should help you produce a solution.

**Update:**
you state in a comment that point `P0` should lie on a given line (please add this to your original problem statement). This means you can rewrite `y0` as a function of `x0`:

```
y0 = a*x0 + b
```

where a and b are given.
This reduces the complexity of your distance functions and makes derivation a serious possibility.

```
D1 = sqrt((x0-x1)^2 + (ax0+b-y1)^2)
D2 = sqrt((x0-x2)^2 + (ax0+b-y2)^2)
..
Dn = sqrt((x0-xn)^2 + (ax0+b-yn)^2)
```

But if the amount of points `n` is not too large I would just do a brute-force search* in the  area of the line where x is close to the mean of x1 .. xn to find the point x-, y0 that minimises D0.

Comment: Interesting.  Given the specific limitations the OP imposes and his (sane) aversion to mathematically complex solutions, I suspect the simpler newton's or more robust gradient descent solutions are easier to demonstrably get correct and more than fast enough - notably, wikipedia claims there is no exact algebraic solution anyhow, you need iterative refinement.

Comment: that is what I meant. The iterative solution given in the wikipedia page is as easy as it gets. By the very nature of this problem there is only one minimum, and there are no local minima, so convergence is guaranteed. Note by the way that centroid != Geometric median.

Comment: Thanks for giving the exact term "Geometric median". I was searching, what is it called.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:

d1=1 & d2=10  (sum=11 & sumOfSquares=101)

d1=6 & d2=6   (sum=12 & sumOfSquares=72)

Sum increased but sum of squares decreased.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the minimization of an objective function given by some norm of your distances. The distances are Euclidean, and as such represent the Euclidean norm between two vectors. In order to understand the difference between minimizing sum(ai) over sum(ai^2) I recommend you read the [Wikipedia entry on Norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29); bottom line, notice the following:

```
||x||2       <= ||x||1 <= sqrt(n)||x||2
||x||_\infty <= ||x||2 <= sqrt(n)||x||_\infty
||x||_\infty <= ||x||1 <=       n||x||_\infty
```

Where `||x||2` is the Euclidean norm, `||x||1` is `sum(abs(x1)+abs(x2)+...+abs(xn))`, and `||x||_\infty` is `max(abs(x1),abs(x2),...,abs(xn))`. In your case all the numbers are positive (you already have the Euclidean norm, so you can seee the difference.

It may also be helpful (though much more difficult to fully grasp) to read the fantastic book by Golub and Van Loan, *Matrix Computations*.